# Imagemagick compression from command line causing buffer error for TIFF

Tags: node.js, command-line, compression, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to use ImageMagick command line to compress TIFF files by spawning child processes from node.  Certain commands cause no issue, such as monochrome and despeckling.

```
      let tiff2png = spawn('C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8\\convert.exe', [
    path,
    '-monochrome',
    '-normalize',
    '-despeckle',
    targetPath]);
```

This raises no errors, but outputs TIFF files of 17MB when the source files are around 2.5MB.  I've tried adding

```
-compress BZip
```

to my args both prior to saving to the targetPath and iterating over the targetPaths after they've been converted.  Both attempts log out buffer errors from the following event watcher:

```
  tiff2png.stderr.on('data', (data: any) => {
    console.log('stderr: ', JSON.stringify(data));
  });
```

I've stringified the error in order to expand the error object, hoping to see some useful details.  The full error just contains a type of "Buffer" and a uselss array of numbers:

```
stderr:  {"type":"Buffer","data":[99,111,110,118,101,114,116,46,101,120,101,58,32,117,110,114,101,99,111,103,110,105,122,101,100,32,111,112,116,105,111,110,32,96,45,99,111,109,112,114,101,115,115,32,66,90,105,112,39,32,64,32,101,114,114,111,114,47,99,111,110,118,101,114,116,46,99,47,67,111,110,118,101,114,116,73,109,97,103,101,67,111,109,109,97,110,100,47,49,50,51,57,46,13,10]}
```

Certain other ImageMagick commands throw the same error, such as -contrast-stretch and -level.  This is the last element of a project, and I've been trying to get it to work for the last two days.  This is on a 64-bit Win10 Ultimate machine, hence the Windows pathing in the commands.

I've tried wrapping the output in a writeFileSync, but with no success.  I have a feeling that this is a file streaming issue, but I can't discern the exact nature.  I'd be grateful if anyone could help me find details about the error or a solution.

Comment: I don't believe `BZIP` is a valid TIFF compression type - try `LZW`.

Comment: Other options appear to be `FAX`, `GROUP4`, `JPEG`, `REL` or `ZIP` so maybe try those for your scenario too.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all compression options using:

```
identify -list compress
```

**Sample Output**

```
B44
B44A
BZip
DXT1
DXT3
DXT5
Fax
Group4
JBIG1
JBIG2
JPEG
JPEG2000
Lossless
LosslessJPEG
LZMA
LZW
None
Piz
Pxr24
RLE
Zip
RunlengthEncoded
ZipS
```

If you pipe that into `tiffdump` you can see which ones result in a value other than `1` in the TIFF tags:

```
for f in $(identify -list compress); do 
   echo $f
   convert -size 1024x768 xc:red +noise random -compress $f a.tif
   tiffdump a.tif | grep -i "^Compression"
done

B44
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
B44A
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
BZip
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
DXT1
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
DXT3
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
DXT5
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
Fax
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<3>
Group4
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<4>
JBIG1
convert: CompressionNotSupported `JBIG1' @ error/tiff.c/WriteTIFFImage/3590.
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
JBIG2
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
JPEG
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<7>
JPEG2000
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
Lossless
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
LosslessJPEG
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
LZMA
convert: CompressionNotSupported `LZMA' @ error/tiff.c/WriteTIFFImage/3590.
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
LZW
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<5>
None
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
Piz
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
Pxr24
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
RLE
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<32773>
Zip
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<8>
RunlengthEncoded
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<32773>
ZipS
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
```

Which implies, to me, in my environment at least, that the only valid compression types for TIFF with ImageMagick are:

```
FAX, GROUP4, JPEG, RLE, LZW or ZIP
```

---

Also, `-monochrome` as well as `-normalize` seems superfluous to me, since the former means *"only use blacks and whites"*, and the latter means *"stretch the range of pixels to the limits of black and white"*.

---

Also, have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Compression) and as far as I can see, `BZIP` is not mentioned there either.

Comment: I appreciate the thoroughness of this reply.  I followed your steps and found the same compression types you did, but they all threw the same error.

Comment: I also removed -monochrome from my args.  I appreciate the explanation on the similarities of those processes.

Comment: Maybe try the same command at the commandline in a Command Prompt and see if there is an error. Also try checking what compression gets used in the output file `magick identify -verbose OUTPUT.TIF | FINDSTR /I compress` or somesuch under Windows.

Comment: I did try it from Powershell, and it worked without issue.  I ended up writing a Powershell script to handle the entire batch.  Thanks!